# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Dont use pending intent

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I pull the Target SDK version of my application from 30 to 31, I get the following error.

> Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
> continuation of the error
>
> at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
> at
> android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:645)
> at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:632)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.getPendingIntent(ForceStopRunnable.java:273)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.isForceStopped(ForceStopRunnable.java:151)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.forceStopRunnable(ForceStopRunnable.java:171)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run(ForceStopRunnable.java:102)
> at
> androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)

I dont use Pending Intent or any Broadcast Receiver in my application.

BUILD.GRADLE / MODULE

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        def nav_version = "2.3.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.10'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

BUILD.GRADLE / APP

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude("META-INF/*.kotlin_module")
    }

    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility "11"
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    //Material Design
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    //Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.4.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'

    //Navigation
    def nav_version = "2.3.5"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

    def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
    // ViewModel
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    // LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"


    // Dagger dependencies
    def dagger_version = "2.27"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$dagger_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"

    // Hilt dependencies

    def hilt_version = '2.28-alpha'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"

    // Hilt ViewModel extension
    def hilt_jetpack_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel:$hilt_jetpack_version"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hilt_jetpack_version"

    //Retrofit
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.0")
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.9.0")
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.7.1'

    //java8
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'

    //Qr Code
    implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'

    //Stetho
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-urlconnection:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.1'

    //Glide
    api 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'

    //Firebase
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.1.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'

    //Swipe Delete
    implementation 'com.ernestoyaquello.dragdropswiperecyclerview:drag-drop-swipe-recyclerview:0.6.0'

    implementation 'com.github.emreerkahraman:MPAndroidChart:v4.0.1'

    implementation 'com.github.mkw8263:MindevPDFViewer:1.0.4'

    implementation 'com.otaliastudios:zoomlayout:1.7.0'

    //EasyImage
    implementation 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:3.0.3'

    //Image Crop UI
    implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.6-native'

    //Joda Time
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.10.10'

    //PhotoView Zoom
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'

    //PinCodeView
    implementation 'com.github.antoxa2584x:PinCodeView:1.3.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.8.6'

    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'

    implementation 'com.andrognito.flashbar:flashbar:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:2.0.0'

    //Sentry
    implementation 'io.sentry:sentry-android:6.21.0'

    //Kotlin Reflect
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.31"

    //Skeleton Effect
    implementation 'com.faltenreich:skeletonlayout:4.0.0'

    implementation 'com.vmadalin:easypermissions-ktx:1.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'


}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
        pickFirst "META-INF/library_release.kotlin_module"
        //exclude "META-INF/DEPENDENCIES"
    }
```

I have tried update libraries, kotlin version or any. It creates another problems.

i tried `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1`

Comment: The error log in you post doesn't show, but the very end of the stack trace in your error log might tell you which package is causing this error.

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920) @RickyMo

Answer (score 0):

[Following the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent#getBroadcast(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))

For a **PendingIntent** you have to pass a **immutable** flag since Android 12+.

Without the proper flag the **PendingIntent** is considered **mutable**.

[image: Flags description from official documentation]

Please read carefully the documentation and try using some immutable flags, if this doesn't help let me know and I'll provide more support.

Comment: OP mentioned that he is not using PendingIntent. So the problem is probably one of the dependencies is using PendingIntent but OP don't know which one is.

Comment: There has to be something using a PendingIntent, probably a library since he is using a lots of libraries in the project. I would try to isolate single libraries and see what's causing the error.

Comment: i didnt find, i tried all possible libraries